# Android: Launch music player service from application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I know that it is possible to launch the music player using an intent using either of the follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
startActivity(intent);
```

However is it possible to start the default music player as a SERVICE rather than an activity? Moreover, is it possible to send actions to that service once it has been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However is it possible to start the default music player as a SERVICE rather than an activity?

No, in part because there is no requirement for the user's chosen music player to even *have* a service. Moreover, the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` action is only generally supported by activities.

> Moreover, is it possible to send actions to that service once it has been created?

Not generally.

There thousands of "music player" apps for Android, any of which can be the "default" for a given user and device. You are welcome to ask each and every one of them if they offer some sort of command-based interaction with some sort of music-playing `Service` to allow third-party apps to control their player. Some might. Most won't.